# Share wishlist email not being sent

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates, wishlist, email-translation

Emails are being sent correctly (subsription, registration, etc...), but the share wishlist email is not being sent.

Email is not present in admin panel `system/tools/SMTPPro - Email Log`.

Where I should begin to look to find what's not working? Which are the best steps to find the origin of the problem?

If I go to `magento_path/app/design/frontend/theme/template/wishlist/sharing.phtml`

I see that the share wishlist button is in a form, and the action form is `<form action="<?php echo $this->getSendUrl() ?>" id="form-validate" method="post">`.

So I look into `magento_path/app/code/core/Mage/wishlist/Block/Customer/Sharing.php` where getSendUrl() method is. And I place a log in this method:

```
Mage::log($this->getUrl('*/*/send'), Zend_Log::INFO, 'email_send.log', true);
```

The log in the file after trying to send the share email is:

```
2018-01-29T09:16:02+00:00 INFO (6): https://myweb.com/en/wishlist/index/send/
```

Once I see this I look into the wishlist index controller, the sendAction. And I place some logs there:

```
$emails  = explode(',', $this->getRequest()->getPost('emails'));
Mage::log($emails, Zend_Log::INFO, 'email_send.log', true);
$message = nl2br(htmlspecialchars((string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('message')));
Mage::log($message, Zend_Log::INFO, 'email_send.log', true);
```

the $emails var is:

```
2018-01-29T09:28:47+00:00 INFO (6): Array
(
    [0] => pim@youremail.cf
)
```

That is the email in entered

and the $message var is:

```
2018-01-29T09:28:47+00:00 INFO (6): 
<div style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0; padding:15px; background:#F9F9F9;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650">
        <tr>
            <td width="32%">
                <p align="center" style="font-size:12px;"><a href="https://myweb.com/en/foo-sunset-eclipse.html"><img src="https://myweb.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab3352/F/o/foo-sunset-eclipse.jpg" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" width="135" height="135" alt="" /></a></p>
                <p align="center" style="font-size:12px;"><a href="https://myweb.com/en/foo-sunset-eclipse.html" style="color:#203548;"><strong>foo sunset eclipse/ natural</strong></a></p>
                <p align="center" style="font-size:12px;"><a href="https://myweb.com/en/foo-sunset-eclipse.html" style="color:#1E7EC8;">Product view</a> <small>
            |</small> <a href="https://myweb.com/en/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHb3oyLmJlbm29tLdpc2hsaXNQv/product/1210/form_key/vtdo2iaN/nocookie/1/" style="color:#1E7EC8;"><strong>Add to Cart</strong></a>            </p></td>
            <td width="2%"></td>
    </table>
</div>
```

that is the email template I'm trying to send.

**Edit: Solution**

I find the wishlist email sending code from the wishlist indexcontroller commented. I uncomment it and now emails are sent:

```
//this code was commented. So it prevented wishlist emails from being sent
foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $emailModel->sendTransactional(
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_template'),
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_identity'),
                $email,
                null,
                array(
                    'customer'       => $customer,
                    'salable'        => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                    'items'          => $wishlistBlock,
                    'addAllLink'     => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/allcart', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'viewOnSiteLink' => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'message'        => $message
                )
            );
        }
```

Comment: Place a log where email code is there for sending wishlist email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the wishlist email sending code from the wishlist indexcontroller commented. I uncomment it and now emails are sent:

magento_path/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/controllers/indexController.php
look for sendAction() method.

```
//this code was commented. So it prevented wishlist emails from being sent
foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $emailModel->sendTransactional(
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_template'),
                Mage::getStoreConfig('wishlist/email/email_identity'),
                $email,
                null,
                array(
                    'customer'       => $customer,
                    'salable'        => $wishlist->isSalable() ? 'yes' : '',
                    'items'          => $wishlistBlock,
                    'addAllLink'     => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/allcart', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'viewOnSiteLink' => Mage::getUrl('*/shared/index', array('code' => $sharingCode)),
                    'message'        => $message
                )
            );
        }
```

I know that code/core code should never be edited, it must be overwritten instead.

Comment: I just asking, is possible user can add more than one wishlist creation for their own name like  Amazon.